# Math software / language for analytic / multiplicative number theory

Tags: analytic-number-theory, mathematical-software, multiplicative-number-theory

**What software/languages are the most used to do computations in analytic / multiplicative number theory?**

I use Python, Maple, etc., but each time I want to compute expressions like, for $n$ with an actual numerical value,

$$\sum_{P^+(a) \leq u \\ P^-(b) > v\\a\ b = n} \mu(a) \mu(b)$$

(just a random example), there seems to be no native (and short-syntax) way to do sums over divisors, etc.

I'm looking for a language/software that can (at least) do, with a short syntax, numerical computations, but also (would be cool) some formal simplifications, e.g. if you have $\sum_{d | n } \mu(d)$, it would simplify it automatically, etc.

Note: I already read [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/100925/computational-number-theory), but it doesn't specifically address the question of specific multiplicative number theory simplifications.

Comment: I'm not sure such a thing exists today, but one could imagine a small set of motivated people writing a helpful package for one of these software packages (or Sage, Mathematics, etc.). For example, I have from time to time written code to evaluate general multiplicative functions in Mathematica.

Comment: I would be interested in such a language implementing Euler products, Dirichlet convolution, the theory of $\zeta(s)$, so we could ask things like the asymptotic and explicit formula of $\sum_{n \le x} 2^{\omega(n)}$ and its Mellin transform, with or without assuming the RH.

Comment: Pari/GP: It does sum over divisors with fordiv. Assuming that $P^+,P^-$ are the largest/smallest prime factor, your sum is (probably) something like fun(n,u,v)=r=0;fordiv(n,a,b=n/a;f=factor(a);if(a!=1&&b!=1&&f[matsize(f)[1],1]<=u&&factor(b)[1,1]>v,r=r+moebius(a)*moebius(b)));r

Comment: This seems interesting @FelipeVoloch. Could you post as an answer with a few details to explain? Thanks a lot!

Comment: There isn't much to explain (I even found that there is a sumdiv function that makes it even easier to sum over divisors). The only hacky part is to extract the smallest and largest prime factor from the factorization of a number which is given in matrix form (and avoid the factorization of $1$, which is slightly different). The other commands are standard and explained in the documentation.

Comment: Also I've noticed with most languages (Maple, or R with package [`numbers`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/numbers/numbers.pdf)), it's quite slow when you do sum with functions involving prime factors of $n$. Are there some software in which a prime factors list could be precalculated once for all for $n=1..10^K$ (or loaded from a big dump) (I mean without having to reinvent the wheel myself)?

Comment: Pari/GP does that too. It is meant to be used for number theory. You should try it.